# Metro has encountered an error: ENOENT: no such file or directory '@babel/runtime/package.json': node:fs (596:3)

Tags: react-native, expo

[image: error image]
I'm trying to build by react-native app to my iphone and I run into this error. I've tried removing the node_modules and reinstalling. I have no idea what is causing this, here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "workoutapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.24.0",
    "@expo-google-fonts/kadwa": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "~3.1.3",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@fanchenbao/react-native-scroll-indicator": "^0.2.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.18",
    "expo": "^49.0.23",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.3.0",
    "expo-font": "^11.10.2",
    "expo-haptics": "~12.4.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-sqlite": "~11.3.3",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.10",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-dots-pagination": "^0.3.1",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
    "react-native-haptic-feedback": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-markdown-display": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-markdown-package": "^1.8.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  }
}
```

I have tried removing the node_modules and reinstalling, I've tried different versions of expo/react-native, i've tried removing the ios folder and rebuilding. I was expecting it to build with no errors but here we are.